# Query for numerical varchars and compare them, with querydsl

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Lets say I have three tables, profile and profile_elements (one to many association) and element_type.

profile_elements has all elements of the profile and also the element_type_id as a foreign key to element_type table and has a column "value" that is VARCHAR.

I want to make an advanced search into profile_elements. When I work with Strings of course there is no problem but if for example I want to make a comparison (greater than etc) with values of the "value" column I cant, even if I know that i.e. when the element_id=1 then these values gonna be numerical varchars. 
I've tried to build a predicate like

```java
QprofileElements.profileElements.any().elementId.eq(1).and(QprofileElements.profileElements.any().value.castToNum(Long.class).gt(12345)
```

but hibernate handles it as two separate select-from-where queries and it tries to cast to long all values of the columns so an error occurs when it tries to convert a value that contains characters. I even managed to make it so hibernate sees it as one query of the form

```
where element_id=1 AND cast(value)>12345
```

but it still has the same problem.

Is there a way to overcome this problem with querydsl or something else? And if it isn't, is there a way to construct this query

```sql
select * 
from(
  (select * from profile_element pe where pe.element_id=1)
) as sq 
where cast(sq.value as int8)>12345
```

with querydsl?

I've tried JPAExpressions too, even when().then(), nothing seems to work

Versions

- Postgresql 9.5
- hibernate 5.4
- querydsl 4.2.1

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a varchar column? That's a huge mistake to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested SELECT, you can simply write:

```
select * 
from profile_element pe 
where pe.element_id = 1
 and cast(pe.value as int8) > 12345;
```

When using a SQLQueryFactory the following works for me:

```
QprofileElements pe = new QprofileElements("pe");
queryfactory.
  select(pe.all()).
  from(pe).
  where(pe.attribId.eq(1).
    and(pe.attribValue.castToNum(Long.class).gt(1)));
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I have tried this QueryDSL expression but doesnt work. The db query indeed works but as I understand this is not always necessary to be true. Regarding the storing of numbers in Varchar, its happening because there are many types of the value (for example it can be string up to 5, up to 20, number with 10 digits, float etc).

Comment: @zlash: I don't know this `any()` method, but with a SQLQueryFactory and using `select()` the code in my edited answer works.

Comment: Still has the same problem! It's creating two separate queries  and it itterates all the table so as a result when it tries to cast a value containing characters throws an error.

Comment: @zlash: thecode in my answer creates a **single** query - at least when using QueryDSL with "plain SQL". It will run: `select ... from profile_element pe where pe.attrib_id = ? and cast(pe.attrib_value as int8) > ?`. However, I have no experience with adding an obfuscation layer like Hibernate on top of QuerySQL.